# Make div go on new line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the 'div' go on another line on `@media query max-width 321px` but keep the same design on desktop, I've tried to `float: left` and put the `.aboutBox` as `width: 100%` but still no luck.

This is what I am trying to achieve for mobile: imgur.com/byoafCc however this is what happens on the desktop css: imgur.com/tSwOJI4

HTML

```
    <div id="aboutContainer">
    <div class="aboutBox">
      <h2>WHAT IS SHARPTURN NETWORK</h2>
      <p>Sharpturn Network is a multi marketing platform that specialises in advertisement and promotion.</p>
      <h2>HOW DID IT START</h2>
      <p>Ryan Williams and Dan Lewandowski began building the business plan, brand design and website layout in 2014 and it was given a huge reconstruction in early 2016 with a more mature
      approach.</p>
    </div>
        <div class="aboutBox">
      <h2>WHAT IS SHARPTURN NETWORK</h2>
      <p>Sharpturn Network is a multi marketing platform that specialises in advertisement and promotion.</p>
      <h2>HOW DID IT START</h2>
      <p>Ryan Williams and Dan Lewandowski began building the business plan, brand design and website layout in 2014 and it was given a huge reconstruction in early 2016 with a more mature
      approach.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Desktop CSS:

```
#aboutContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #505050;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
  }

  .aboutBox {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 600px;
  }

  .aboutBox h2 {
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .aboutBox p {
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
```

Mobile CSS:

```
#aboutContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #505050;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
  }

  .aboutBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
  }

  .aboutBox h2 {
    font-family: 'Questrial',sans-serif;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .aboutBox p {
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
```

Comment: In mobile.cs you've not cleared float, which is assigned left in desktop css

Comment: Have a look at SkelJS, usefull tiny JS framework to use a grid system where divs can go on a new line on small screen. It is really easy to use

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

in this demo is mobile add `display:inline-block;` in this `id` file `#aboutContainer`

```
#aboutContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #505050;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
  }

  .aboutBox {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

  }

  .aboutBox h2 {
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

  }

  .aboutBox p {
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align:justify;
  }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/hyLcndm2/2/)

**AND**

DESKSTOP DEMO

```
#aboutContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #505050;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
  }

  .aboutBox {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .aboutBox h2 {
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .aboutBox p {
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/hyLcndm2/4/)

sorry my poor english

Comment: What should OP try. Explain what is required changes in your answer. It will help to understand problem better.

Comment: i was changed in  height :auto; @ketan

Comment: Add that thing in answer too. So, future user can understood the problem

Comment: is that CSS mobile or desktop? and Thanks :) @IvinRaj

Comment: Desktop only @partians

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve for mobile: http://imgur.com/byoafCc
however this is what happens on the desktop css: http://imgur.com/tSwOJI4

Comment: Hey @IvinRaj it made the desktop to become a list aswell, any way I can do it as desktop like this: http://imgur.com/aQCAyE4
and mobile like this: http://imgur.com/w34p1Ko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102662/discussion-between-partians-and-ivin-raj).

Comment: hey @partians  sir first u said desktop like this: http://imgur.com/tSwOJI4  Now us said like this method http://imgur.com/aQCAyE4

Comment: wait @partians i will do it

Comment: please check it now sir @partians